# Suppose 3 points $A$, $B$, and $C$ lie on a line $L$. Then $B$ lies in between $A$ and $C$ iff $(B-A)\cdot (B-C) < 0$.

Tags: geometry

***Problem:*** Suppose 3 points $A$, $B$, and $C$ lie on a line $L$. Then $B$ lies in between $A$ and $C$ iff $(B-A)\cdot (B-C) < 0$.

It seems the forward direction that $(B-C) = -(B-A)$ so that $(B-A)\cdot   (B-C) = - (B-A) \cdot (B-A) < 0$.

The backwards statement of the proof is confusing me. Where can I begin to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of the forward direction assumes that $B$ is exactly between $A$ and $C$. However, even if this is not true, we can write $B-C = c(B-A)$ for some $c  < 0$. Then, $(B-A)\cdot (B-C) = c\|B-A\|^2 < 0$.

If $B$ is not between $A$ and $C$, then without loss of generality, let $C$ be between $A$ and $B$ (otherwise, we let $A$ be between $B$ and $C$, and the rest of the proof works exactly the same way). Then, $B-C = c(B-A)$ for some $c > 0$, so $(B-A)\cdot (B-C) = c\|B-A\|^2 > 0$. Therefore, we have shown that if $B$ is not between $A$ and $C$, then $(B-A)\cdot (B-C) > 0$. Thus, the contrapositive (which must also be true) is that if $(B-A)\cdot (B-C) < 0$, then $B$ must be between $A$ and $C$.

Of course, this all assumes that $B$ is distinct from $A$ and $C$ (in which case we'll never have that $(B-A)\cdot (B-C) = 0$, since $B-C$ and $B-A$ are nonzero and not perpendicular).